# How do we create pojo class and set values for array of JSON

Tags: api, pojo, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, test-data

How do we create pojo class and set values for array of JSON

Sample

{

"expiresAt": "2022-04-28T09:28:00.890Z",

"qualifiers": [

```
{

  "dataType": "INTEGER",

  "key": "/account.ACCOUNT_NO",

  "operator": "GT",

  "value": "value123"

},

{

  "dataType": "INTEGER",

  "key": "/account.ACCOUNT_NO",

  "operator": "GT",

  "value": "value123"

}
```

]

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Parent class

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class ParentObject {
    private String expiresAt;
    private List<NestedObject> qualifiers;
}
```

Child class

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class NestedObject {
    private String dataType;
    private String key;
    private String operator;
    private String value;
}
```